# IOS Section Footer Cell Height based on Content

Tags: ios, uitableview, dynamic, label, height

i need to create a custom footer for a section within a table view. The footer contains a text (label) and a button underneath it.

The problem is that the text has a different length in different languages. How can I create the footer with  a dynamic height based on the content from the label?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the height of the footer view by calculating the estimated size of the label according to the text inside of it, adding the height of the button and adding perhaps another small value for padding.
Here's a Swift example:

```
let theLabelFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(FONTSIZE)
let labelRect = (yourLabelText as NSString).boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(LABEL_WIDTH, CGFloat.max), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:theLabelFont], context: nil)

let footerHeight: CGFloat = labelRect.height + (YOUR_BUTTON).frame.height + somePaddingValue
```

Then simply return it in the `heightForFooterInSection:` method.